# Error cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance with prcomp

Tags: pca

I have a data set with 290 observations and 24475 features,
I split the data set to train data set and test data set with this code:

```r
set.seed(107)
y <- dim(data)[2]-1
require(caret)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = data[, y],p = precent_of_partition,list = FALSE)
training <- data[ inTrain,]
testing <- data[-inTrain,]
```

when I try to perform pca on the train set: `pca.result <- prcomp(expression_matrix, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)`

I get this error:

> Error in prcomp.default(expression_matrix, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE) : 
>   cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance

but if I perform pca on the all data set I dont get error at all and it works,

can someone clarify what is hepping? how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

After you use R stdio to read data,you can use:

```r
data1 <- data[,apply(data, 2, function(x) all(x > 0))]
pca.result <- prcomp(data1,center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
```

The function is deleting the zero in your dataset.